# How to make accordion tabs in different color when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to design accordion in the following way... http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/1/ as shown on fiddle.

I need to two things to be fixed.

**One**: How to keep first Tab open by default.

**Second**: How to show each active tab in different colour when that particular tab contents are active or visible.

Let us say when active

Example One: In Blue colour
Example Two: in red colour
Example Three: In yellow colour.

```
<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#one">Example one</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#two">Example two</a>

    </li>    
    <li>
      <a href="#three">Example three</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
        <div id="one" class="accordion">
        ONE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium. 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
      <div id="two" class="accordion">
        TWO Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
        <div id="three" class="accordion">
        THREE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet in laborum praesentium esse aliquam molestiae animi non facilis perspiciatis corporis ad molestias quo harum suscipit ipsum incidunt ea voluptates accusantium.
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using some accordion script like http://code.anotherwebstorm.com/apps/awsaccordion/

Comment: "*How to show each active tab in different color"* - by tab you mean the accordian head, not its content, right?

Comment: Since you've tagged `jQuery`, you can try [jQuery UI Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a click on the first anchor on `ready()` to show the first accordian by default: Note that you should trigger it on the native element rather than the jQuery element.

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
$("a:first")[0].click()
```

CSS:

```
a[href="#one"].active{
  background:blue !important;
}
a[href="#two"].active{
  background:red !important;
}
a[href="#three"].active{
  background:yellow !important;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/3/)

Comment: [just a note] You can avoid using `!important` using high specificity.

Comment: @Mr_Green yep...  if i do that the selector will be too long and might scare the OP :D *(hopefully he gets it from the comment)* bit lazy as well :)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker any specific reason for unaccepting the answer? as far as i can see *currently* accepted answer doesn't keep the first tab open, which is the point one in question..as far as i can see, it doesn't *completey* answer the question atm.

Comment: @T J, it was accidental ... revert back to original

Answer (score 1):

this is possible with jQuery

```
<a href="#one" colr="red">Example one</a>
```

chage color of custom color attribute that you want

```
$('#accordion a').click(function(){
    $('#accordion a').css('backgroundColor','transparent');
    $(this).css('backgroundColor',$(this).attr('colr'));

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your HTML to get this effect.

#### Added CSS:

```
#accordion div#one.accordion:target + a {
    color: blue;
}
#accordion div#two.accordion:target + a {
    color: red;
}
#accordion div#three.accordion:target + a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

#### Altered HTML: (*example*)

```
<div id="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div id="one" class="accordion">ONE.......</div>
            <a href="#one">Example one</a>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="two" class="accordion">TWO.........</div>
            <a href="#two">Example two</a>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="three" class="accordion">THREE........</div>
            <a href="#three">Example three</a>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/7/)**

Comment: It keeps active line in red color only while it should show links in different colors

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker np.. actually, I learnt new stuff by referring your code. Thanks :)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I missed the point that you need to show first tab by default. For that I think it is possible using Javascript. Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcLnowa/8/).

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, I guess the only thing you can do is to append the hash `#one` to your page url or to use jQuery.

For the second problem, you can add this to your css:

```
#one {
    border-color: #C00;
}
#two {
    border-color: #FF0;
}
#three {
    border-color: #CF0;
}
```